# Possible to get the Freeform plugin to send to different admins based on locale

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace

I'm using the [Solspace Freeform](https://solspace.com/craft/freeform) plugin.

If someone submits a form on `/de/contact` I want it to go to a German admin

If someone submits a form on `/en/contact` I would like it to go to an English admin.

In Expression Engine, you used to be able to set recipients in the template.

Is the best way to deal with this to setup a "Dynamic Recipient" field, then hide it in the markup and somehow deal with this on a locale conditional?

Comment: I usually make a seperate form per locale, to handle translations etc. a bit better. Found that this usually is the best solution

Comment: Hmm, certainly one solution, but seems over kill & potentially quite a lot of work if you have lots of locales. It seems like Freeform fields have translated field labels for their default fields, so, probably wasn't intended to be like that.

Comment: I've contacted the people at freeform for a similar question, but their answer was the following:  "All that said, this is something very complicated to implement, and working it into Composer interface further complicates things. However, this is something that's on our list to consider adding in the future. :)".